# Sun Java System Portal Server 7.1

Tags: java, system, sun, portal-server

I guess I can extend the base providers to manipulate the base layout etc.Is there any place where I can get the java source code for default providers? Where are the classes for these default providers copied to ?What are list of things that I can manipulate by extending base containers? Is there a comprehensive documentation on methods that i can override?

Thanks a lot for your time!!

Regards,
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

The developer's guide you can find here should answer your questions about the default providers:

http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/coll/1483.1

The open source version of the portal project/source code can be found here:

https://portal.dev.java.net/